# How to center image in StackView conditionally

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have a StackView containing a UIImageView and a UILabel. Sometimes the UILabel contains a quotation and sometimes it does not. When it does I want the UIImageView to be 40% of the device width - I have that part working. When it does not I want the UIImageView still to be the same width, just centered horizontally. What's the easiest way to achieve this?[image: StackView]

[image: StackView Settings]

Comment: 2 sub stackviews and hide the second stackview when label has empty string. Or just hide the label.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that UIStackView is not what you really need there, but rather simple `UIView`, which is centered vertically in the parent view, and contains `UIImageView` and `UILabel`, and then set `imageView.trailing` equal to `label.leading`, plus `label.sizeToFit()`.

But if you want to stick to your design, what you could do is programmatically set UIStackView axes. For instance, set stack view in IB like:

[UIStackView IB setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aMt7.png)

and then in code in `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
if label.text == "" {
    stackView.axis = .vertical
} else {
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
}
```

also with `label.sizeToFit()`.

That should do the trick.